# How to adjust the size of a chip in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to display a large number of chips in my view with text inside it. Since the count is big I want to decrease the size of the chip to the minimum. Specifically the height of the chip. How can this be done?

```
for (EPDiaryTarget target in widget.item.targetList) {
    Chip chip = new Chip(
      label: new Text(
        target.name,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFa3bdc4),
    );
    studentsChips.add(chip);
  }
```

I've given `padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0),` for the chip but its default size is not reduced. Can a custom shape with required size be given to a chip? If so, How can it be done? Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can wrap the chip in a `Transform` widget and scale it as follows:

```
    Transform(
      transform: new Matrix4.identity()..scale(0.8),
      child: new Chip(
        label: new Text(
          "Chip",
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFa3bdc4),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is the best solution in this case, as it also scales the text inside the chip, which is most probably not desired.

Comment: and it keeps the total size so if they are beside each other there is a giant gap between them

Comment: You can reverse transform the text of the label with another transform. This scales up the text again. At least addressing the issue of shrinking the size of the chip. Any other solution would be appreciated.

Comment: just a side note, a cleaner version to the answer: Transform.scale(
                          scale: 0.8,
                          child: (...)
                        )

Comment: I love flutter but these things can be so annoying... Can't we just adjust the size without rapping up with a random widget :/

Answer (score 33):

You need to set `materialTapTargetSize`. Default value is `MaterialTapTargetSize.padded`, which sets minHeight of 48px for the chip. Set it to `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` to remove the extra space.

```dart
Chip(
  ...,
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Moreover it works also on 'RawChip'

Comment: If you have a bunch of chips in a `Wrap`, so that you have chips on successive lines, then this moves the chip text tightly together, but the colored backgrounds of the chips overlap.

Answer (score 25):

Wrap label: Text('chip') in Container or SizedBox.

```
Chip(
    label: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 40,
        child: Text('chip'),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I really like this approach, since Text is widget with the dynamic width in most of the cases.

Answer (score 22):

Now you can use VisualDensity (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VisualDensity-class.html) which is a double that can be between -4 and 4 ([VisualDensity.minimumDensity], [VisualDensity.maximumDensity])

Comment: ```visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: -4)``` Thanks, solved a chip bug for me.

Comment: This is a way better answer and even got the pill shape I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To set `labelPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, -6, 0, -6)`

Comment: Setting negative values worked fine on Android, but caused errors on iOS.

Comment: @kaboc For me it's the opposite. This works fine on iOS but crashes the app on Android and Web, but only when a emoji is in the chip.

Answer (score 2):

try with negative padding

labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -6, horizontal: -4)

i also suggest you try with some negative padding according to your design and see the changes in flutter inspector then your problem will be solve or one more thing don't wrap chip widget with container or not fix the height and width just provide the label padding [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flKxJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps to use badge plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/badges#-example-tab-

It is not native widget from flutter. But it address the size issue here.

Answer (score 0):

## Flutter 3.19.0

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

#### Code

```
ChoiceChip(
  visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: -4), // Add this line
  selected: true,
  selectedColor: Colors.white,
  checkmarkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
  label: Text(
    "Chip 1",
    style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
  ),
)
```