# How to scale Chip layout box along with Chip inside Wrap in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Inside a Wrap I have an array of StatelessWidget representing tags. Right now, the child widget simply returns a Chip. The build method for my Tag widget looks like:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Chip(
        label: Text('#the-tag-name'));
  }
```

The Chips render like so:

[image: Original]

I'd like to render smaller chips, so following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440984/how-to-adjust-the-size-of-a-chip-in-flutter), I've updated it to this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform(
      transform: Matrix4.identity()..scale(0.8),
      child: Chip(
          label: Text('#the-tag-name')),
    );
  }
```

This is the result:

[image: Scaled]

I'd like to retain the initial spacing between the Chips, but it seems that the transform isn't transforming the original layout size of the Chip:

[image: Scaled with debug paint]

The debug paint shows additional non-scaled padding to the right and bottom of each chip. Is there any way to remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to stay away from using `Transform`. It can lead to unintended consequences.

The reason your `Chip` padding won't go any smaller is because it is restricted by Material specifications. A clickable widget has a minimum `tapTarget` size. You can test this out by looking at the `materialTapTargetSize` on your chip.

CMD+click on the `shringWrap` and you will see that it says: "Shrinks the tap target size to the minimum provided by the Material specification."

```
Chip(
   label: Text('#the-tag-name', 
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0)),
   materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
),
```

So if you really need to shrink your widget, your best bet is to go another route. Possibly by using a `RawMaterialButton` like this: The padding and textSize can be adjusted as needed.

```
RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  constraints: BoxConstraints(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0),
  child: Text(
    '#the-tag-name',
    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
  ),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
  ),
  fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
),
```