# what is differencebetween spacing and runSpacing in Flutter Wrap() Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: this is the image]

what is difference between spacing and run space  named parameter Flutter Wrap() Widget and also run alignment property please explain that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spacing` is the space between the children in the main axis and `runSpacing` is the space in the cross axis.

Consider this example (for default alignment)

[image]

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 300,
  child: Wrap(
    spacing: 20.0, // Horizontal space.
    runSpacing: 30.0, // Vertical space.
    children: <Widget>[
      apple,
      ball,
      champion,
      destructor,
      eagle,
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Widget Wrap spacing means the space between two widget in main axis

Widget Wrap runSpacing means the space between two widget in cross axis

Check this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5iw2SeFx2M

Answer (score 0):

`spacing: 10.0` : gap between adjacent box (How much space to place between children in a run in the main axis.)

`runSpacing: 20.0` : gap between lines (How much space to place between the runs themselves in the cross axis.)

Answer (score 0):

This question is #1 ranked when searching for SO questions to remove the `Chip`
padding/spacing within the `Wrap` widget.

That's what I found after reading several questions.

This also works for `RawChip` widget.

Props to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61558450/11793117.

---

#### 1. Remove `Wrap` spacing

Make sure to set `Wrap`'s `runSpacing` and `spacing` properties to 0:

```dart
Wrap(
  ...,
  // Left/right spacing between the elements
  spacing: 0,
  // Top/bottom spacing between the elements
  runSpacing: 0,
);
```

These are the default values at the time, so it probably won't solve the problem.

#### 2. Change `Chip` minimum tap target size

You may need to set the `materialTapTargetSize` property. Default value is `MaterialTapTargetSize.padded` which sets minHeight of 48px for the chip. Set it to `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` to remove the extra space.

```dart
Chip(
  ...,
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
)
```